# Elastic Search Singular and Plural Words showing different count

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 6.x. When I tried search for apple and apples its showing different results count. Any solution to allow singular and plural words to get same result count when I search.

Comment: You will have to setup a stemmer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html

Comment: May you show your [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) and the query you make? Also a couple of example documents would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using an existing analyzer "snowball":

```
{
 "settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
                "type": "snowball"
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

}